# Tinymce is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, tinymce

I am trying to use tinymce for my django project but its not working.
I installed it by using "pip install django-tinymce" and i am trying to use if for the admin change form template. please find the code below.

chanage-form.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
{{ media }}
<script >
define(['jquery', 'tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce'], function ($) {
    $('textarea').tinymce({
        script_url : 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        theme : 'advanced',
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,removeformat,indent,outdent,numlist,bullist,copy,paste,link',
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : '',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left'
   });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode: "textareas",
theme: "simple"
});
</script>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of thoughts.

Should the javascipt include in the html look like, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

There are a few different ways to set up how the static files for tiny mce are served, this line works for me with a new project in Django 1.6. It is probably worth checking the 2 different urls in the browser to make sure the `tiny_mce.js` is being served correctly.

I also had to add:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'tinymce',
    ...
)
```

In `settings.py`, again this step isn't always required it depends on how you set up tiny mce...